# Detect Characters In Any Order

Tags: php, strpos

I'm sorting a username registration system, and part of our protocol is that users can only use A-Z, a-z, 0-9, _, ., and -. In addition, they can't have two punctuation marks in a row.

I'm trying to find an easier way to detect the punctuation other than just writing out the physical strings:

```
if (strpos($string, "..") !== false || strpos($string, "._") !== false || strpos($string, "-.") || strpos($string, ".-"))
```

(The above doesn't include all cases; Just showing a few for example)

Is there an easier way to check the string for a math of two specific characters in a row in any order?

Thanks!

Comment: Probably with a regex, but that's a strange limitation. What harm does it do to have two consecutive punctuation marks in a username?

Comment: Another developer I'm working with asked for the feature and the project leader didn't have any objections. It seems to just be for a less-messy user base

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Validate against allowed symbols:

```
if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9.,_-]/", $string)){
     throw new Exception("Illegal characters in username");
}
```

Check if two ore more punctuation marks are next to each other:

```
if (preg_match("/[.,_-]{2,}/", $string)){
     throw new Exception("Two or more nearby punctuation symbols are not allowed in username");
}
```

Comment: And the letters and numbers?

Comment: The letters / numbers I have in a different match so I can throw the exact error for what the user has. i.e. "Username contains too many chars", "username contains illegal symbols", etc.

This seems to be very helpful for what I want done. Just going to do some testing.

Comment: added another check for general check against valid symbols.. otherwise, it's up to you to add multiple checks to see what you want to check for.

Comment: This seems to do what I need. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_match()](https://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

```
if(preg_match('/\.{2,}|([^a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)/', $username) {
    // invalid username
} else {
    // the username is valid
}
```

The regex will find an invalid usernames: either at least two consecutive dots, or a character outside of the list of the allowed ones.

Comment: Not ending in a dot wasn't part of the OP requirements, I think it's more likely than having two periods in a row, and what's wrong with having a username like "steve." ?

Comment: I don't have an issue with the name ending in a punctuation mark, the only thing is the name can't have two marks in a row (i.e. it can't be "steve..." but it could be "steve." or "steve_"